# AWS ALB Ingress Controller and ingress resource for python app

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress, aws-alb

I have created python app following this link https://kubernetes.io/blog/2019/07/23/get-started-with-kubernetes-using-python/. I want to configure `AWS ALB Ingress Controller/nginx controller` and `ingress resource` but I am unable to understand the file. I don't have a domain using Kops on ec2-instance, want to configure it without any domain. Any help would be appreciated.

deployment:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: hello-python
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: hello-python
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: hello-python
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: hello-python
        image: hello-python:latest
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5000
```

service

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: hello-python-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: hello-python
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - nodePort: 30010
      port: 6000
      targetPort: 5000
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An Ingress binds a Service like `hello-python-service` above to an ALB through the nginx ingress controller.

It does so by mapping a virtual host to your service so that nginx knows how to route requests.

example:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: python-ingress
  namespace: default
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: ingress-controller-nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/default-backend: hello-python-service
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1

spec:
  rules:
    - host: python.trash.net
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /?(.*)
            backend:
              serviceName: hello-python-service
              servicePort: 6000
```

would generate a resource of class `Ingress` like the below:

```
python-ingress   python.trash.net   internal-0358a08f01385b2812-331143124.us-east-2.elb.amazonaws.com   80      10s
```

issuing a curl request like this:

```
curl -H "Host: python.trash.net" http://internal-0358a08f01385b2812-331143124.us-east-2.elb.amazonaws.com
```

should get you a response from your hello python app.

This obviously depends on you having the nginx ingress controller deployed and configured in your EKS cluster.

The key takeaway for an ingress is this:  It replaces the need for a dedicated service of type LoadBalancer to provide external access to your service.  Instead, Ingress maps traffic from outside the cluster to services in the cluster through a virtual host that is configured in the Ingress' manifest file.

Comment: I don't have to configure ingress controller separately, the example you provided would do that for me? Am I right?

Comment: i don't have any domain how would I route traffic without a domain name?

Comment: the nginx controller is not configured by default in EKS.  You will need to set it up.  You will also need to define a domain in Route53 if you wish to route traffic to your service without setting the Host: header.